# Compare part of sha1 digest with hex string in C

Tags: c, hex, sha1

I have a string for which I compute a sha1 digest like this:

```
SHA1(sn, snLength, sha1Bin);
```

If I'm correct this results in a 20 byte char (with binary data). I want to compare the last 3 bytes of this char with another char. This char contains the string "6451E6". 64, 51 & E6 are hex values. How do I convert "6451E6" so that I can compare it via:

```
if(memcmp(&sha1Bin[(20 - 3)], theVarWithHexValues, 3) == 0)

{

}
```

I have this function:

```
/*
 * convert hexadecimal ssid string to binary
 * return 0 on error or binary length of string
 *
 */
u32 str2ssid(u8 ssid[],u8 *str) {
    u8 *p,*q = ssid;
    u32 len = strlen(str);

    if( (len % 2) || (len > MAX_SSID_OCTETS) )
      return(0);

    for(p = str;(*p = toupper(*p)) && (strchr(hexTable,*p)) != 0;) {

      if(--len % 2) {
        *q = ((u8*)strchr(hexTable,*p++) - hexTable);
        *q <<= 4;
      } else {
        *q++ |= ((u8*)strchr(hexTable,*p++) - hexTable);
      }
    }
    return( (len) ? 0 : (p - str) / 2);
}
```

which does the same but I'm new to C and don't understand it :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix for AShelly's code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int hashequal(const unsigned char *sha1Bin, const char *hexstr) {
    unsigned long hexvar = strtoul(hexstr, NULL, 16);
    unsigned char theVarWithHexValues[] = { hexvar >> 16, hexvar >> 8, hexvar };
    return memcmp(sha1Bin + 17, theVarWithHexValues, 3) == 0;
}

int main() {
    unsigned char sha1Bin[20];
    sha1Bin[17] = 0x64;
    sha1Bin[18] = 0x51;
    sha1Bin[19] = 0xE6;
    printf("%d\n", hashequal(sha1Bin, "6451E6"));
    printf("%d\n", hashequal(sha1Bin, "6451E7"));
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Can you explain to me what happens here: unsigned char theVarWithHexValues[] = { hexvar >> 16, hexvar >> 8, hexvar };

Comment: @tersmitten: the `{}` introduce an array initializer - each comma-separated term in the list becomes one `unsigned char` value in the array. When an unsigned int is converted to unsigned char, it is simply taken modulo 256 (assuming an 8 bit char), so `hexvar` converted to `unsigned char` is the least significant 8 bits of `hexvar`, i.e. the last two hex digits. The least significant 8 bits of `hexvar >> 8` is the 9-16th bits of `hexvar`, and the same for `hexvar >> 16`. This code doesn't work if there are more than 8 bits in a byte, but that's rare (some DSPs and some mainframes, basically).

Comment: ... if needed, it can be fixed by changing `hexvar >> 16` to `(hexvar >> 16) & 0xff`, and the same for the other two, presuming that the sha1 hash on that system is presented as 20 bytes, each containing 8 bits of hash value with any additional bits in the byte set to 0.

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to go the other way — convert the binary data to a hex string for comparison:

```
char suffix[7];
sprintf(suffix, "%02x%02x%02x", sha1Bin[17], sha1Bin[18], sha1Bin[19]);
return stricmp(suffix, theVarWithHexValues) == 0;
```

Even if you prefer converting to binary, `sscanf(...%2x...)` is better than manually parsing hex numbers.

Comment: Maybe that's true but speed is very important (19000000 iterations) and I would like not to touch the sha1Bin part. theVarWithHexValues on the other side is const. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I suspect that memory bandwidth will dominate, so this version might surprise you. Or it might not, just don't assume anything. Also, I don't know what you mean by "touch the sha1Bin part". My code doesn't modify sha1Bin in any way.

Answer (score 1):

If `theVarWithHexValues` is indeed a constant of some sort, then the easiest thing would be to put it into binary form directly.  Instead of:

```
const char *theVarWithHexValues = "6451E6";
```

use:

```
const char *theVarWithHexValues = "\x64\x51\xE6";
```

...then you can just `memcmp()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* hexstr = "6451E6";
unsigned long hexvar = strtoul(hexstr, NULL, 16);
hexvar = htonl(hexvar)<<8;  //convert to big-endian and get rid of zero byte.

memcmp(&sha1Bin[(20 - 3)], (char*)hexvar, 3)
```

Comment: This is wrong on a big-endian architecture because the first byte will be the high-byte with value zero, and wrong on a little-endian architecture because the bytes will be reversed.